# CSS to add to Jekyll Minima, not completely override it

Tags: html, css, jekyll

I am building my first Jekyll site and am happy with the Minima theme as a starting point. I would however like to customise some aspects of the site, such as colours, adding elements to layouts etc.

However, whenever I create a stylesheet or layout in the following structure(currently empty files, as I want to add supplementary elements ad hoc)

```
/
 --assets
   --main.css
 --_layouts
   --default.html
```

It overrides the default layout and style, leaving a styleless website.

How can one supplement the Jekyll Minima theme, without overwriting the default?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

By virtue of the way gem-based Jekyll themes work, any file at source-directory take precedence over the same file if it exists in the theme-gem. i.e., `<source>/_sass/minima.scss` will override the entire `<theme-gem>/_sass/minima.scss` by its mere presence.

To make simple changes like changing the color,
alter the variable values in `_sass/minima.scss`

To alter layout styles, copy both `_sass/minima.scss` and `_sass/minima/_layout.scss` to source, and then alter the `_layout` partial

---

Or if you simply want to **add** to Minima, do the following:

- First create a new sass sheet (say, `custom.scss`) in **your** `_sass` directory.
- Then into **your** `assets/`dir, copy the `main.scss` from Minima
- Then **add** a new `import` rule to the copied `main.scss`:

  ```
  @import "minima";
  @import "custom";
  ```
- Now whatever styles you add to `custom.css` should be picked up by Jekyll

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. This is the thing that was causing confusion for me, there appears to not be a default _sass directory. In fact the only default directory aside from _site that I have is _posts. I did however create an _includes directory for MathJax.

Comment: since v3.2.0 and advent of gem-based themes, `_layouts`, `_sass` and `_includes` are bundled within a theme-gem. From v3.3.0, even `assets` got bundled within a theme-gem

Comment: I've written a small plugin called [`jekyll-extract`](https://github.com/ashmaroli/jekyll-extract) to facilitate easy copying of a theme-gem file to the source-directory

Comment: Fantastic. I shall try this when I am at my PC later today. Thank you.