# Load MathJax on github page using jekyll without overwriting layout

Tags: jekyll, github-pages, mathjax

I have a GitHub Pages site setup with Jekyll: https://davidelegacci.github.io/Research/. I need to load MathJax to display math content, but doing so I end up overwriting the layout, obtaining a style-less page.

**How can I load MathJax without overwriting the layout?**

Some details. The root directory is

```
.
├── README.md
├── _config.yml
├── _layouts
│   └── default.html
├── hamiltonian
│   └── some_content.md
└── learning
    └── some_content.md
```

*Without loading* the `default.html` layout anywhere the `_config.yml` is

```
plugins:
  - jekyll-relative-links
relative_links:
  enabled: true
  collections: true
include:
  - README.md
```

Note that there is no theme installed. I guess Github uses some default stylesheet (that seems to be https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/). I like this default style, but math is not rendered:

[image: Default css, no math]

I added the `default.html` layout to all pages and posts adding [Front Matter Defaults](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/front-matter-defaults/) to `_config.yml`:

```
defaults:
  -
    scope:
      path: "" # an empty string here means all files in the project
    values:
      layout: "default"
```

and I loaded MathJax in `default.html`

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <!-- inline config -->
  <script>
    MathJax = {
      tex: {
        inlineMath: [['$', '$'], ['\\(', '\\)']],
        macros: {
         RR: "{\\bf R}",
         bold: ["{\\bf #1}", 1],
         indep: "{\\perp \\!\\!\\! \\perp}",
       }
     },
     svg: {
      fontCache: 'global'
    },
  };
</script>

<!-- load MathJax -->
<script type="text/javascript" id="MathJax-script" async
src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js">
</script>

</head>
<body>
  {{content}}
</body>
</html>
```

The script to load MathJax is taken from here https://my1396.github.io/Econ-Study/2023/10/12/Mathjax.html and official documentation is here https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/web/configuration.html.

Now both inline and display LaTex is rendered correctly, but any style is lost:

[image: no style, yes math]

**How can I load MathJax without overwriting the layout?**

Related: I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45769857/css-to-add-to-jekyll-minima-not-completely-override-it) but it refers to a Jekyll-based site without GitHub pages, and I got quickly lost in gem stuff, that I completely ignore.

Comment: FWIW, the default theme that gets applied if nothing is set in `_config.yml` is https://github.com/pages-themes/primer

Comment: And that default is set in the pages-gem [here](https://github.com/github/pages-gem/blob/974872fe73f8ec0b704e48f5c1f150df7a508e01/lib/github-pages/configuration.rb#L19), and the default action to build pages is [jekyll-build-pages](https://github.com/actions/jekyll-build-pages)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add to [Benjamin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3266847/benjamin-w)'s [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77794919/load-mathjax-on-github-page-using-jekyll-without-overwriting-layout#comment137145645_77794919), you can make sure the Primer theme's stylesheet is included in your `default.html` layout. Since [GitHub Pages uses the Primer theme by default](https://github.com/github/pages-gem/blob/974872fe73f8ec0b704e48f5c1f150df7a508e01/lib/github-pages/configuration.rb#L19), you should explicitly link to it in your custom layout to maintain the style when you override the default layout.

Since [primer v0.6.0](https://github.com/pages-themes/primer/releases/tag/v0.6.0), you can override the includes instead of the entire default layout ([PR 61](https://github.com/pages-themes/primer/pull/61)).

You find that page mentioned in "[How to use Latex(MathJax) on Minimal Mistakes GitHub blogs](https://choimon.github.io/blog/mathjax-for-minimalmistakes-githubpage/)" by [Minjeong Choi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10808879/minjeong-choi)

> There are multiple ways to do this.
> You could add the MathJax script part directly in `_includes/scripts.html`, `/_includes/head/custom.html`, or `/_includes/footer/custom.html`, but I chose to create a separate HTML for this extra support.
>
> `_includes/mathjax-custom.html`:
>
> ```html
> <script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
>   MathJax.Hub.Config({
>     extensions: ["tex2jax.js"],
>     jax: ["input/TeX", "output/HTML-CSS"],
>     tex2jax: {
>       inlineMath: [ ['$','$'], ["\\(","\\)"] ],
>       displayMath: [ ['$$','$$'], ["\\[","\\]"] ],
>       processEscapes: true
>     },
>     "HTML-CSS": { availableFonts: ["TeX"] }
>   });
>
>
>   MathJax.Hub.Register.MessageHook("Math Processing Error",function (message) {
>     alert("Math Processing Error: "+message[1]);
>     });
>   MathJax.Hub.Register.MessageHook("TeX Jax - parse error",function (message) {
>     alert("Math Processing Error: "+message[1]);
>     });
> </script>
>
>
> <script type="text/javascript" async src="https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML">
> </script>
> ```
>
> in `_layouts/default.html`, I added the following at the end:
>
> ```html
>   {% if page.use_math %}
>     {% include mathjax-custom.html %}
>   {% endif %}
> ```
>
> (You can skip this step if you added the script in `_includes/script.html`, `/_includes/head/custom.html`, or `/_includes/footer/custom.html`.)
>
> my `default.html` would look like this:
>
> ```html
> ---
> ---
>
> <!doctype html>
> <!--
>   Minimal Mistakes Jekyll Theme 4.22.0 by Michael Rose
>   Copyright 2013-2020 Michael Rose - mademistakes.com | @mmistakes
>   Free for personal and commercial use under the MIT license
>   https://github.com/mmistakes/minimal-mistakes/blob/master/LICENSE
> -->
> <html lang="{{ site.locale | slice: 0,2 | default: "en" }}" class="no-js">
>   <head>
>     {% include head.html %}
>     {% include head/custom.html %}
>
>   </head>
>
>   <body class="layout--{{ page.layout | default: layout.layout }}{% if page.classes or layout.classes %}{{ page.classes | default: layout.classes | join: ' ' | prepend: ' ' }}{% endif %}">
>     {% include_cached skip-links.html %}
>     {% include_cached browser-upgrade.html %}
>     {% include_cached masthead.html %}
>
>     <div class="initial-content">
>       {{ content }}
>     </div>
>
>     {% if site.search == true %}
>       <div class="search-content">
>         {% include_cached search/search_form.html %}
>       </div>
>     {% endif %}
>
>     <div id="footer" class="page__footer">
>       <footer>
>         {% include footer/custom.html %}
>         {% include_cached footer.html %}
>       </footer>
>     </div>
>
>     {% include scripts.html %}
>
>     {% if page.use_math %}
>       {% include mathjax-custom.html %}
>     {% endif %}
>   </body>
> </html>
> ```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, but the css stylesheet you linked results in a 404. I actually found the correct procedure in the theme documentation, adding my script in `_includes/head-custom.html`

Comment: @DavideL Well done and good catch. I have rewritten the answer to illustrate that approach, from a similar blog post I have found.